# Creating class object c++ in if-statement

Tags: class, object

I actually have a small question. I want to create an attribute "function" which should be from the class function1, function2 or function3. Is there a way I can do that?

Here is the code:

```
double Uppersum::evalIntegral(double p_) {
    if (functiontype == FUNKTION1){
        Function1 function;
    }
    else if (functiontype == FUNKTION2) {
        Function2 function;
    }
    else if (functiontype == FUNKTION3){
        Function3 function;
    }

    function.setParameterP(p_);
    double increment_h = (boundary_b - boundary_a)/num_subintervalls_m;
    double sum = 0;
    for (int index_i = 0; index_i < num_subintervalls_m -1; index_i++){
        double x_1 = index_i * increment_h;
        double x_2 = (index_i+1) * increment_h;

        double y_1, y_2;
        y_1 = function.evalFunctionValue(x_1);
        y_2 = function.evalFunctionValue(x_2);

        sum += increment_h * std::max(y_1, y_2);
    }
}



class Function {
 protected:
    double parameter_p;

public:
    void setParameterP(double p_);
    virtual double evalFunctionValue(double x_)=0;
};



class Function1 : public Function {
public:
    double evalFunctionValue(double x_);

};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use inheritance, superclass has the virtual functions setParameterP and evalFunctionValue. and in subclasses, override those virtual functions.

here is the test code：
test.cpp

```
    #include <iostream>
    typedef enum{
        FUNCTION1,
        FUNCTION2,
        FUNCTION3
    }FunctionType;

    using namespace std;
    class super
    {
    public:
        super(){}
        ~super(){}
        virtual void setParameterP() = 0;
        virtual void evalFunctionValue() = 0;
    };

    class func1:public super
    {
    public:
        func1(){}
        virtual void setParameterP(){cout<<"call setParameterP In func1"<<endl;}
        virtual void evalFunctionValue(){cout<<"call evalFunctionValue In func1"<<endl;}
    };

    class func2:public super
    {
    public:
        func2(){}
        virtual void setParameterP(){cout<<"call setParameterP In func2"<<endl;}
        virtual void evalFunctionValue(){cout<<"call evalFunctionValue In func2"<<endl;}
    };

    class func3:public super
    {
    public:
        func3(){}
        virtual void setParameterP(){cout<<"call setParameterP In func3"<<endl;}
        virtual void evalFunctionValue(){cout<<"call evalFunctionValue In func3"<<endl;}
    };

    class FuncFactory
    {
    public:
       static super* create(FunctionType var)
       {
           super* ret = nullptr;
           switch (var)
           {
               case FUNCTION1:
                    ret = new func1();
               break;
               case FUNCTION2:
                    ret = new func2();
               break;
               case FUNCTION3:
                    ret = new func3();
               break;
               default:
                cout <<"invalid FunctionType" << endl;
           }
           return ret;
       }   
    };

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    super* pFunc = FuncFactory::create(FUNCTION1);
    pFunc->setParameterP();
    pFunc->evalFunctionValue();
    delete pFunc;

    pFunc = FuncFactory::create(FUNCTION2);
    pFunc->setParameterP();
    pFunc->evalFunctionValue();
    delete pFunc;

    pFunc = FuncFactory::create(FUNCTION3);
    pFunc->setParameterP();
    pFunc->evalFunctionValue();
    delete pFunc;
    return 0;
}
```

here is the process result:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RET6.png)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I actually already have a super class, which is called "Function". In this class define the setParameterP and the virtual function evalFunctionValue. I also have three subclasses Function1, Function2, and Function3. 

The problem ist, that the compiler doesn't know what datatype the variable function(see above). It always gives me the error: Can't resolve variable or class "function".

Comment: I just updated the code a bit, hope that will help to solve the problem.

Comment: Read the improved code above,do not construct subclass object,do construct superclass object by a factory method(FuncFactory::create(FunctionType var) in test.cpp).You should use the factory method instead if-statement.